# domain and range problems for a function

Tags: functions

While finding domain and range of function f(x) = (4-x)/(x-4), domain should be not equal to 4, but this function can also be written as f(x) = -1, if considering this, there should not be any limitation of not having domain should also include  4. Are these functions equal? if not, then what is the difference between these functions?

Comment: What do you mean domain equal to $4?$ I think you want to say domain contains $4.$

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I mean to say that, domain should also include 4

Comment: This is like asking if anything divided by the opposite of itself is equal to $-1$. Is this the case for *all* numbers?

Comment: no, for 0 this is not true

Comment: Correct. And in this case we end up attempting to compute $0/0$ if we have $x=4$ in the first function

Comment: but, if i do some arithmetic, i got, f(x) = -1, and this does not means that we are dividing two opposite numbers. Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Given some formal expression $f(x)=(\dots)$ it is up to you to *choose* domain and codomain in a sensible way, depending on what you want to express with the function. There is no god-given choice that can be derived from the formal expression.

Now, assuming you want $x$ to be a real number, you see that the denominator vanishes at $x=4$, which might be a problem. So you could define $f:D\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on the domain $D=\{x\in \mathbb{R},x\neq 4\}$. As $f$ is continuous on $D$, a reasonable question is, whether it extends continuously across the gap, or more precisely, whether there is a continuous function $\tilde f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x) = \tilde f(x)$ for all $x\neq 4$. Indeed, this is possible, by chosing $\tilde f(x) = -1$ for all $x$. The formal expression you started with is however completely independent of this question about maps.

Comment: thank you for you answer, but, I didn't get what you said in last two lines, if possible can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

Although there is another answer I'll post this because I had already typed it out.

It comes down to the definition you use for your function.  The first expression has no meaning when $x=4$, so the point $x=4$ is excluded from the domain.  The second is defined for all $x$.  The two functions just happen to agree at all points that they are defined.

There are ways around this.  One is to include the point $x=4$ explicitly in your first definition, for example,

$$ f(x) = \left\{ \array{ \frac{4-x}{x-4}, & \text{ when } x \neq 4 \\ -1, & \text{ when } x = 4 } \right. $$

Which causes the two version to agree everywhere.  But of course if you chose a different value at $x=4%$ they would agree everywhere except when $x=4$.

Another approach is to argue using continuity.  Although the first form is undefined at $x=4$, it can be extended uniquely if you add the condition that the extended function should be continuous.  Then the function $y = -1$ is the unique continuous extension.

I hope this is a useful explanation.